# "Uncaught TypeError: is not a function" in Vuejs without use CLI

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, scroll

I want to make a scroll in vue where I go loading more data down with a function that lists the data, the question is that I only want to execute the scroll function and that the list function is executing and in reality I am using a code that already It has worked for me in other projects but it keeps marking the error of

> Uncaught TypeError: this.cargarLista is not a function

```
mounted() {
    this.cargarLista();
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            this.cargarLista();
        }
    });
},
```

By simple logic it should work since I'm only calling the function.
Even try using scroll function in vanilla js without jQuery

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    window_width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
    window_height = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
    scrollTop =  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    body = document.body;
    html = document.documentElement;
    height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight ); 
    height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight ); 

    if (scrollTop + window_height == height) {
        this.cargarLista();
    }
});
```

The funny thing here is that as you can see in mounted() I am executing the same function outside the scroll and there it does not give me any error and nowhere else actually since I use the function for other cases and it does not give me any error only when I want to run it on the scroll

**It should be noted that I am not using the vue CLI only the CDN in a .js file**

I would appreciate if someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Normal functions `function() {/* code here */ }` change `this` (You get a brand new `this` inside the function), while arrow functions `() => { /* code here */ }` do not. They use the outer `this`. That's one of the main differences between the two.